# member login, is there a way to include member id to return parameter?

Tags: members, login

I tried to use return="site/profile/{member_id}" in my member:login form, but that did not work, giving 0 to segment 3.

I also did try {logged_in_member_id} with no success.

Is there a way to return with valid member_id in segment 3, so that I could pull out content only for the logged in member to be shown?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's going to be tough, since `{member_id}` isn't available until _after_ log in. Why not just check `{logged_in_member_id}` within the "site/profile" page template and proceed accordingly?

Comment: Destination URL ("site/profile") in form return then gets redirected automatically to site/profile/{logged_in_member_id}?  That way the variable will be set once they have submitted the form and the redirect will work. But ensure that no-one else can just enter that URL to access other people's information...!

Comment: Yep. I did came to a conclusion that I just put "profile" link to top bar with the tag on 3rd segment, and some conditionals against it to check out group id. By that I get 2 different setups with all the things I need instead of using one Long Template with "if's" in it.